# android studio sdk v23 webview get geolocation

Tags: android, html, webview, geolocation

yet another question regarding this issue.  Sorry to be redundant, but I've looked everwhere and still I can't get this to work.  My webpage navigator.geolocation function returns this error: **The application does not have sufficient geolocation permissions.**  It doesn't ever ask the user if they'll allow permission.  Everything works in different browsers on my desktop (chrome, ff, safari, ie 10 +).

I'm running an emulator in android studio... the phone type is a nexus 5 api 23 (android 6.0).

Here's the hodgpodge of code I have for this by now:

//my mainActivity.java file:

```
  @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
    WebSettings mWebSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    mWebSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    String userAgent = mWebView.getSettings().getUserAgentString() ;
    mWebSettings.setUserAgentString(userAgent);

    mWebSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mWebSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    mWebSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    mWebSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    mWebSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    mWebSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
    mWebSettings.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

    mWebView.clearCache(true);
    mWebView.clearHistory();
    mWebView.clearView();
    mWebView.loadUrl("https://mywebsite.com");


    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()
    {
        @Override
        public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
            callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
        }

etc...
```

//my android manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I'm stuck stuck stuck.  Starting to wonder if this is even possible... how to people get this to work?!?!?!?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use AppCompatActivity, not plain activity, this does the trick:

```
@Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
//your code
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        }, 0);
//your code
}
```

Starting from Android 6, API level 23, permission handling has changed. You should ask permission for critical functionalities (like location) from user explicitly in runtime.